# Google App Engine oauth2client dependency

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine

I'm working on google app engine with a python2 to python3 conversion.

One of my imports is

> from oauth2client.contrib.appengine import CredentialsNDBProperty

This errors on

> from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import login_required
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.appengine.ext.webapp'

I am thinking I am missing a dependency, can I ask for assistance?
Here is my requirements.txt so far

````
flask==2.2.5
flask-login==0.6.3
flask-oauthlib==0.9.6
flask-restful==0.3.10
google-cloud-ndb==2.2.1
honcho==1.1.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
Flask-BasicAuth==0.2.0
urllib3
google-api-python-client==2.122.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.2.0
webargs==8.4.0
grpcio==1.62.1
appengine-python-standard>=1.0.0
simplejson==3.19.2
iso8601==2.1.0
requests-toolbelt==0.10.1 
createsend==7.0.0
oauth2client==4.1.3```
````

Answer (score 0):

The library is deprecated: see https://github.com/googleapis/oauth2client/tree/master.

Also see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/services/access#web_frameworks

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me find the replacement dependency to  CredentialsNDBProperty?

I'm using google.appengine.ext

Comment: @ffejrekaburb - The oauth2client pip page has suggested libraries to use in place of oauth2client. You have to look at those libraries and write code to replace what you're currently doing with oauth2client.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the oauth2client dependency. I asked another question looking for guidance on how to reimplement CredentialsNDBProperty which was being imported.